# AVAudioSession current route output/MPVolumeView wireless route active

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, avaudiosession, mpvolumeview

I can't find the way to get the name of the audio session current route output because AVAudioSession gives you a list of outputs for its current route, therefore there can be more than one, and using MPVolumeView, you can know if there is a wireless route active, but you can't know its name or type.

Thanks.